# Android Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT (only use specific apps from ResolveInfo)

Tags: android, android-intent

Running into a little snag here giving users options for selecting a photo from the gallery. On certain phones, that have more apps which claim to handle the intent users get them as a choice... is there a way to filter that in a standard manner to just the standard issue photo gallery?

Is the first item in p.queryIntentActivities will always be the gallery?

Here is what we are doing to get the list of apps....

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.setType("image/*");
i.putExtra("return-data", true);
PackageManager p = new PackagerManager();
List<ResolveInfo> list = p.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
```

So if we just get one resolveinfo... great!  But if we get multiple items in the list... filtering by packageName seems kind of hacky since we don't know what packageName will be... there are just too many different phones out there.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On certain phones, that have more apps which claim to handle the intent users get them as a choice... is there a way to filter that in a standard manner to just the standard issue photo gallery?

No, because there is no "standard issue photo gallery".

> Is the first item in p.queryIntentActivities will always be the gallery?

No.

> Any advice?

Allow the users to pick an image from any app they choose that supports `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for `image/*` MIME types.

Comment: if we allow the user to pick app, onActivityResult capture this dialog and resultCode comes false. so i want to disable this dialog and open gallery directly. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to use a specific app from ResolveInfo: 
This is helpful when you know exactly which one to use and do not want to display the "complete action using" dialog.

1. query for apps that respond to Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT:

   ```
   Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
   intent.setType("image/*");
   mApps = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
   ```
2. mApps will hold a list of all apps that support the Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent.
3. Fire startActivityForResult for your desired app:

   ```
   ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(position); // depends on which app you want to start
   String packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   intent.setPackage(packageName); // this will direct the intent to your specific app
   intent.setType("image/*");
   intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
   ...
   startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
   ```